# How to disable the keyboard in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I want to make a calculator in Android Studio and have a textedit I want to keep to be able to select every part of a calculation at any time. My problem is, that whenever I click the textedit the system keyboard pops up. How can I prevent this from happening? (My phone is using the standard samsung keyboard if that is of any relevance)

I already tried  using

```
android:windowSoftInputMode = "stateAlwaysHidden"
```

in the AndroidManifest.xml file, but it didn't work. I also know how to forcefully close it, but not how to keep it closed. Other questions on this side couldn't really help me any further either.
I found a way to disable the keyboard whenever I touch the edittext, but it feels half baked and doesn't work the first time